# SPNEGO - Exclude specific URL / URL pattern from authentication check

Tags: java, filter, spnego

I implemented Single Sign On into my application. Now I got URL's which I dont want to use with single sign on (for example an unprotected webservice). How I can I do that? Is there an SPNEGO init param, which is supported?

```
<display-name>myapp</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/faces/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.Exception</exception-type>
    <location>/faces/error.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>prototype</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>3</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Now I would like to configure something like this:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>SpnegoHttpFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>net.sourceforge.spnego.SpnegoHttpFilter</filter-class>
[...]
  <init-param>
   <param-name>excludePattern</param-name>
   <param-value>.*rest.*</param-value>
  </init-param>
</filter>
```

Edited: 09/11/2018 01:35 PM

In the SPNEGO sources, in class SpnegoHttpFilter.java I found what I was looking for (including the comment):

```
   @Override
public void doFilter(final ServletRequest request, final ServletResponse response
    , final FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

    final HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
    final SpnegoHttpServletResponse spnegoResponse = new SpnegoHttpServletResponse(
            (HttpServletResponse) response);

    // skip authentication if resource is in the list of directories to exclude
    if (exclude(httpRequest.getContextPath(), httpRequest.getServletPath())) {
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
        return;
    }
```

But now my question is, how does this function retrieve a list of directories to skip authentication?

Comment: Hi, how is this JSF related (other than you using it in your application? I see rest things which you do **not** use as a tag.

Comment: I edited my tags. It does only relate to SPNEGO / URL filtering, implemented in Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After researching a while, including browsing through docussion forums on sourceforge, I was not able to make the SPNEGO skip-authentication-mechanism running. There seems to be no example configuration. I opened a question SPNEGO sourceforce page, but for now I implemented a Workaround.

I took the last build of spnego. (build r9, downloaded [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/spnego/files/builds/)).

In class *SpnegoHttpFilter* I created an global variable, called "excludePattern".

```
private String excludePattern = null;
```

In my web.xml of my web application, I created a new init param as following:

```
<init-param> 
 <param-name>excludePattern</param-name> 
 <param-value>.*rest.*</param-value>
</init-param>
```

In class *SpnegoHttpFilter* I need to read the param of web.xml like this:

```
this.excludePattern = filterConfig.getInitParameter("excludePattern");
```

Afterwords, in class *SpnegoHttpFilter* I go to the function doFilter() and insert following:

```
String url = httpRequest.getRequestURL().toString();
if (Pattern.matches(this.excludePattern, url)) {
   chain.doFilter(request, response);
   LOGGER.fine("Excluded URL requested");
   return;
}
```

Now, the code checks the given pattern against the requested URL. If pattern is part of the URL, authentication will be skipped.

I hope I make the original solution, made by spnego developpers, working soon. As Long as I don't, I go with this workaround.

Comment: Thanks, Ronaldo-CH. Just a slight variation on this approach, sticking closer to existing interface: add a third string argument to the exclude function: the requestURI, then pass `httpRequest.getRequestURI()`  in the call to exclude. Then in the exclude function: add (with an OR operator) this condition:  `requestURI.startsWith(dir)` . So its doing pretty much the same thing the same way with the same web.xml parameters, just examining something "deeper" into the application for the logical path.